# Array syntax error PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I get the error *You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[0]' at line 1 * when trying to update and email.

```
$updatelist = explode(",",$Limited);
print_r($updatelist); // echos Array ( [0] => samplemail@gmail.com [1] => samplemal@yahoo.com [2] => ) 

$totalupdates = count($updatelist)-1;
for ($y = 0; $y < $totalupdates; $y++)
{
  $updatemail = "UPDATE tblusers SET date= '$date' WHERE Email = 'updatelist[$y]'";
  $updatefree = mysql_query($updatemail);

  echo $updatemail;

}
```

What's wrong with the $updatelist[$y] ? Should it loop through $updatelist[0] to $updatelist[1] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
$updatemail = "UPDATE tblusers SET date= '$date' WHERE Email = 'updatelist[$y]'";
```

Try this:

```
$updatemail = "UPDATE tblusers SET date = '$date' WHERE Email = '$updatelist[$y]'";
```

Comment: Oh thanks! I've been staring at that for a moment now but I haven't realized I missed the "$" sign.

Comment: No problem! Those sure can sneak up on you if you're not careful.

Answer (score 3):

change `$updatelist[$y]` instead of `updatelist[$y]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$updatelist = explode(",",$Limited);
print_r($updatelist); // echos Array ( [0] => samplemail@gmail.com [1] => samplemal@yahoo.com [2] => ) 
$totalupdates = count($updatelist)-1;
foreach ($updateList as $key=>$val)
{
     $updatemail = "UPDATE tblusers SET date= '$date' WHERE Email = '".$val."'";
     $updatefree = mysql_query($updatemail);
}
 echo $updatemail;
```

Comment: try to use foreach loop that will give you single value

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
  $updatemail = "UPDATE tblusers SET date= '".$date."' WHERE Email = '".$updatelist[$y]."'";
```

Comment: I thought at first that was it too, but then realized that single-quotes inside double-quoted strings in PHP aren't special characters.  Then I saw the missing `$`. (: